# wxChoice not visible in wxPanel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need to add a drop down box to a panel but it doesn't seem to show up when I add it.

```
WeldProfileDialog::WeldProfileDialog(cMainWindow* parent, wxWindowID id) : wxDialog(parent,id, "Weld Profile Editor")
{
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = DBG_NEW wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    this->SetSizer(mainSizer);
    
    wxBoxSizer* col1Sizer = DBG_NEW wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxPanel* sidebar = DBG_NEW wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    sidebar->SetSizer(col1Sizer);
    mainSizer->Add(sidebar);

    wxChoice* selectProfileType = DBG_NEW wxChoice(this, wxID_ANY);
    vector<wxString> choices = { "Single V", "Double V", "J Groove", "Compound"};
    selectProfileType->Append(choices);
    selectProfileType->SetSelection(0);
    col1Sizer->Add(selectProfileType, 1, wxEXPAND);
}
```

[image: No choice control]

However, when I remove the panel and add it directly to a box sizer it works just fine.

And I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

```
WeldProfileDialog::WeldProfileDialog(cMainWindow* parent, wxWindowID id) : wxDialog(parent, id, "Weld Profile Editor")
{
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = DBG_NEW wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    this->SetSizer(mainSizer);
    
    wxBoxSizer* col1Sizer = DBG_NEW wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    //wxPanel* sidebar = DBG_NEW wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    //sidebar->SetSizer(col1Sizer);
    mainSizer->Add(col1Sizer);

    wxChoice* selectProfileType = DBG_NEW wxChoice(this, wxID_ANY);
    vector<wxString> choices = { "Single V", "Double V", "J Groove", "Compound"};
    selectProfileType->Append(choices);
    selectProfileType->SetSelection(0);
    col1Sizer->Add(selectProfileType, 1, wxEXPAND);
}
```

[image]

Comment: try calling `Layout()` at the end of the function.

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: also please check how do you create the control (Hint: what parent window do you pass)?

Comment: the parent of the dialog or the panel?

Comment: the parent of the control...

Comment: ah! I see now, thank you.

Making the control a child of the panel, instead of the dialog fixed it

Comment: you still need the `Layout()` call, especially if you have much more controls on the panel...

Comment: @doom87er Please consider converting your comment to a full (self) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spotted by @Igor: The problem was that my control was a child of the window instead the panel, which placed it under the panel.

this:

```
wxChoice* selectProfileType = DBG_NEW wxChoice(this, wxID_ANY);
```

into this:

```
wxChoice* selectProfileType = DBG_NEW wxChoice(sidebar, wxID_ANY);
```